# Modify the Template Helpers MasterPage with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using the new Razor view engine with ASP.NET MVC and would like to know how to modify the editor template master page in a similar way to how it is done [in this blog post](http://elijahmanor.com/webdevdotnet/post/Opinionated-ASPNET-MVC-2-Template-Helpers.aspx). Is there any examples on how to do this with Razor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve the same thing with the Razor view engine.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Value = "foo"
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Views:

`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`:

```
@model MyApp.Models.MyViewModel

@{ Html.BeginForm(); }

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Value)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />

@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/Template.cshtml`:

```
<p>Some text before template</p>
@RenderBody()
<p>Some text after template</p>
```

`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/string.cshtml`:

```
@model System.String
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/Template.cshtml";
}
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x)</div>
```

Notice how the `string` editor template has been customized and the `Template.cshtml` used as master layout.

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts with Razor - ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx)